# how to reload / refresh a entity like <img> in A-frame?

Tags: aframe

Is that possible to only reload / refresh a entity like   in A-frame? not the whole A-frame page

```
<img id="front" src="assets/png/front.png">
```

because i want to change the image

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to manipulate the dom in the aframe. For exmaple you can flush the data changes to the dom like this:

```js
document.querySelector('img').flushToDOM();
```

You also can change the attributes of an entity like this:

```js
entity.setAttribute('img', { src: 'assets/png/front.png' });
```

Comment: Thank you for you help！if i want to load different images Automated by time something  like every 10mins i want to use a new images，how can i make it happen

Comment: With using `setAttribute` change the `src` attribute of your image and set a new image URI

Comment: yes but i need to set ，what i mean is Automatic，like i set two or three image URI at first，then every 10mins use new image Automatic

Comment: This is an image slider component. However, you can simply create an image slider by your own. You can find a simple code [Automatic Slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp). Finally, you have to add `document.querySelector('mySlides').flushToDOM();` in the last line of `carousel()` method